# Printer will not print automatically. I have to hit the OK button

Tags: delphi, printing, c++builder, page-size, quickreports

Every time I print a page or pages, I get a message saying *Load Tray 1* or  *press OK* to use available media.

When I hit OK the printer will only print **one** page, then it takes several seconds before I can hit <kbd>OK</kbd> again to print another page.

This is extremely time consuming if I want several pages of the same document printed and it tends to happen using the [`TQRCompositeReport`](http://www.quickreport.co.uk/webinfopage.aspx?WebInfoID=677) component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The print job from the driver is set to print on a specific media.

The first thing to do is decide what paper size you really want to print on:

- *letter* size paper is used in America, but in very few other places;
- most of the rest of the world standardizes on *A4* paper size.

The standard QuickReport component has the `Page->PaperSize` property to control media size:

[image: QuickReport Page property]

The composite report component allows many reports to be combined into a single document (via the 'AddReports' event).

The "problem" is that the `TQRCompositeReport` component has its own media size:

[image: TQRCompositeReport media size]

The default value for `PaperSize` is *Letter* and it doesn't matter if every single report you add has a *A4* size: the composite report keeps the default value.

So choose the correct media size and **check the correspondence** among the `PaperSize` values.